# Jsch removing router's login banner

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I'm using Jsch lib to access the routers in my network, but in some routers are login banners. So i need to read the output, identify the banner, remove it and get only the output of my command. I'm using a channel in exec mode. One solution I thought was to get the last char of the prompt, like ">" or "#", but in the exec mode i just get the output of the commands.

Comment: I thought of a solution to this problem: send a blank command, so the output is gonna be just the banner, get the banner's length and put it into a variable. This work fine, but if someone get another solution, show it.

Thanks.

Comment: I think this is the way to go. If the "login banner" is sent by the remote shell before executing the command, there is no way a client can securly delimit them. Could you post an answer detailing your solution?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm years late to this, but I just solved the problem myself.

If you notice, the session has a method setUserInfo(myUserInfo);

UserInfo is an abstract class. A shell session uses the method 'showMessage(Str msg)' to display the banner.

Since you are using the Exec session, the exec session still calls the showMessage(), so what I did was Extend UserInfo and added my own getMessage(), using showMessage(Str msg) to set my 'String messageVar'.

MyUserInfo was a class from one of the JSCH Examples, which I extended. Here is MyUserInfo:

```
    public static abstract class MyUserInfo
        implements UserInfo, UIKeyboardInteractive {


    public String getPassword() {
        return null;
    }

    public boolean promptYesNo(String str) {
        return false;
    }

    public String getPassphrase() {
        return null;
    }

    public boolean promptPassphrase(String message) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean promptPassword(String message) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void showMessage(String message) {

    }       


    public abstract String getMessage();

    public String[] promptKeyboardInteractive(String destination,
            String name,
            String instruction,
            String[] prompt,
            boolean[] echo) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

here is My Extension.

```
    public class UI extends MyUserInfo{
    String message;

    @Override
    public void showMessage(String message) {
        this.message=message;
        super.showMessage(message); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public String getMessage() {
        return this.message;
    }
}
```

And here is how you use it all:

```
session.setUserInfo(new UI());
    session.connect();
```

((UI)session.getUserInfo()).getMessage();